# Regular expression creation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) a string, but only along the last occurrence of `separator` (which may appear many times), which I can do (see below) but I'd like to create that on the fly (from say, user input) and not have it hardcoded in.

For example:

```
var separator= /abc/;
var stringToSplit = 'ONEabc123TWO45THREEabc67FOUR';
var result = stringToSplit.split(/(\abc)(?!.*\abc)/);
 /*['ONEabc123TWO45THREE', 'abc',  '67FOUR']*/
```

Instead, I would like to do it like this:

```
function make(sep){
     ...magic happens here...
     return superSeparator;
}
var separator = make(/abc/);
var stringToSplit = 'ONEabc123TWO45THREEabc67FOUR';
var result = stringToSplit.split(separator );
/*['ONEabc123TWO45THREE', 'abc',  '67FOUR']*/
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bruno91/Y8yN7/)

Is this possible without splitting it up along all separators and just glueing everything but the last together with [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [*RegExp*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor for this

```
var re = new RegExp(pattern, flags);
```

So, for example,

```
function makeMySeparator(pattern) {
    if (pattern instanceof RegExp) // if input is a RegExp already
        pattern = pattern.source;  // get the string of it's pattern
    return new RegExp('(' + pattern + ')(?!.*' + pattern + ')');
}

makeMySeparator('\\abc'); // /(\abc)(?!.*\abc)/
```

Remember that you'll need to escape backslashes if you're writing *String* literals because otherwise they'll vanish when it is interpreted.

Comment: Thank you! Though, is it possible to use `/abc/` as an argument rather than `'abc'`? I can work around it, but the former would make my code more consistent.

Comment: @Kvothe you could do but you'd still have to create a new _RegExp_ instance so it's not really saving you much. You can get the underlying pattern of a _RegExp_ as a string by accessing `re.source`; I'll edit it in

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with native js:

```
function splitOnLastSeparator(separatorToSplit, separator) {
    var length = separatorToSplit.length,
    index = separatorToSplit.lastIndexOf(separator);
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(separatorToSplit.substr(0, index));
    arr.push(separator);
    arr.push(separatorToSplit.substr(index + separator.length, length));
    return arr;
}
console.log(splitOnLastSeparator('ONEabc123TWO45THREEabc67FOUR', 'abc'));
```

Comment: `19`should be `index`? But I'd rather stick with regex, thanks though.